# after reload page, classlist has gone

Tags: javascript

Hi i would like to add "active" class to "li" elements as below, but after navigato to another page or reload, classlist is gone. how can i fix it?

```js
document.querySelector(".nav-list").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.classList.contains("nav-link")) {
        e.target.closest("li").classList.add("active");

        const page = e.target.getAttribute("href");
        location.assign(page);
    }
});
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" data-id="00"><strong>00</strong>&nbsp;Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="destination-moon.html" data-id="01"><strong>01</strong>&nbsp;Destination</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="crew-commander.html" data-id="02"><strong>02</strong>&nbsp;Crew</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="technology-vehicle.html" data-id="03"><strong>03</strong>&nbsp;Technology</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have to add code that figures out what link in your navigation points to what page you are on when the page loads.

Comment: You cannot modify permanently an HTML page with Javascript (fortunately, otherwise it would be very easy to hack websites).